# Creating URL parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The REST service expects me as the client app to pass him a URL with a structure like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/generic_rates?chart=medications&brand_name=advil&dose=9mg&form=tablet
```

so in the controller he is accessing them like `params[:brand_name]`

But how I should produce something like this in my view and set it to him?  Does Rails have methods that form a URL for us?

Comment: Show output of `rake routes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails creates helpers for routes. Like in the comments, run `rake routes` in terminal and you will get a four columns output: Helper method | HTTP Method | URL | Controller#Action.

To use the "Helper method" you need to append `_path` o `_url`. Probably you have a `generic_rates_path`.

To get a link to the URL you want:

```
= link_to 'Generic Rates', generic_rates_path(chart: @chart, brand_name: @brand.name...)
```

So, you can pass params with the helper.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Ruby on Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
link_to "Ruby on Rails search", :controller => "searches", :query => "ruby on rails"
# => <a href="/searches?query=ruby+on+rails">Ruby on Rails search</a>

link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux")
# => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&amp;baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```